# What does the "At" @ symbol mean in import "from" clause?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, at-sign, exponentjs

I'm checking out the [Exponent](https://getexponent.com/) framework for React Native, and I noticed this line in their demo app:

```
import { ExponentLinksView } from '@exponent/samples';
```

I'm vaguely aware of ES7 decorators, but this doesn't seem like one.

What's the purpose of that little at-sign?

Comment: Thanks! That was driving me crazy.

Comment: To be clear, this has nothing to do with ES6. The actual *value* of the module identifier is platform dependent.